# How to change Openstack working project

Tags: openstack

I have multiple Openstack projects available but every command I execute only is applied to my personal project.

I would like to know how to change the "working project". I do not seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: what commands that you are running? If it is the `openstackclient` or the `keystoneclient`, you need to authenticate yourself with a different project so you will have a different project-scoped session to authorize the other client APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what interface is used by you, I'll provide an solutions based CLI.

- 'openstackrc_youraccount' file (it's ocata version rc file, but important variable is OS_PROJECT_NAME. OS_TENANT_NAME is old version name.)

> ```
> export OS_USERNAME=YOUR_USERNAME
> export OS_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASS
> export OS_PROJECT_NAME=YOU_WANT_TO_WORK_PROJECT_NAME
> export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
> export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
> export OS_AUTH_URL=http://YOUR_CONTROLLER_HOST_OR_IP:35357/v3 
> export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
> ```

- After setting up the project name where you want to work into OS_PROJET_NAME, and then applying the current session.

> ```
> $ source openstackrc_youraccount
> ```

Now you can work at the project you selected.

I hope it helpful to you.